# Redis BZPOPMAX for multiple elements

Tags: redis

`BZPOPMAX key [key ...] timeout`
reads one element, blocking.

I need to return all elements with the highest score (could be just one), and block. Does such a thing exist? I keep on looking for it in python thread queues, kafka, etc.

None of them provide this functionality. There is some theoretical background that I'm missing. Input welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The newly added `ZPOP` family of commands (v5 or greater) follows the same logic as the of List operations. It does not allow the "popping" of multiple elements in a single blocking call.

> Does such a thing exist? I keep on looking for it in python thread queues, kafka, etc.

I'm not clear on what exactly you are looking for. Perhaps the new (v5 or greater) Redis Streams has the solution.

Comment: "I'm not clear on what exactly you are looking for. " -> "I need to return all elements with the highest score (could be just one), and block."

Comment: "all" -> there is always one, unless multiple same-scored elements were added in the same call to ZADD

Comment: Why should they have been added in the same call?